# Image Cache in android

Tags: android, image, caching

I need to download image url and store it in cache as bitmap.My qus is is there any config that i have to do inorder to store the image bitmaps in cache..? Is there any need to create any cache file?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you just can put it in the app's cache (`context.getCacheDir()`). What I'd recommend is to use **[wasp](https://github.com/telly/wasp)**: a  cool Android library to handle Bitmaps safely (safe == avoid `OutOfMemory` exceptions which are pretty common), based on a LRU cache.

It also allows you to download images in the background and get a callback once your image is downloaded... or automatically set the image to an ImageView once it gets downloaded. It is open-source, and is available for Maven users too.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers working on wasp library.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this librairy : https://github.com/square/pollexor

Comment: [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) also offers a very good and very friendly to use UI Spice List module to use. Release 1.4.1 is really nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many images you want to cache, you can probably get away with an in-memory cache using a LruCache. I'd cache the downloaded byte array, not the Bitmap, because Bitmaps are Big Things and decoding byte array -> Bitmap is pretty fast.